# Opening a file and creating a new file in the same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def Function222(inF):
  inF = open("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\FF1\\txttt.txt")
  outputF=open("output.txt", "w")
  lines=inF.readlines()
  for line in lines:
                outputF.write('\n')
                outputF.write(line*4)

  inF.close()
  outputF.close()
```

I need to create a new file called outputF and it should show up in the same folder that the inF is in, the problem is that it doesn't appear in the folder and I searched for the file on my computer but didn't find it

Comment: Why would you expect you output file to be in the same folder as your input file? Your input file has a fully-qualified path, your output file doesn't.

Comment: Also, please indent your code correctly.

Comment: Finally. You don't actually call `Function222` anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the current working directory isn't the directory of the input file. Use `os.getcwd()` to get the current working directory, if it doesnt't match the directory of the input file, then you need to change your working directory first:

```
import os

def Function222(inF):
  inF = open("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\FF1\\txttt.txt")
  #change the working directory
  os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\FF1")
  outputF=open("output.txt", "w")
  lines=inF.readlines()
  for line in lines:
                outputF.write('\n')
                outputF.write(line*4)

  inF.close()
  outputF.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the Path:

```
import os


 path= os.path.abspath("C:/example/cwd/mydir/myfile.txt")
```

open new file in path and write to it